# No colon after property name in object declaration, is it valid?

Tags: javascript

I entered this expression in the Firefox and Chrome Dev Console and I wonder why it is valid JavaScript:

```
var x = { a (b) {} };
console.log(x);
```

`x` is then set to an object with the property "a" containing a function called "a" with an argument identifier "b".
How is this valid JavaScript syntax? The colon is missing after "a" and I do not understand the function definition.

Comment: ES6 short object notation

Comment: `x` is an object with a function named `a` with an argument named `b`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is ES6 / ES2015 syntactic sugar ([Property shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand)).
With ES6:

```
const obj = {
    a(b) { 
        // Shorthand method
        // `this` context is `obj`
    },
    c
};
```

is equal to

```
var obj = {
    a: function a(b) {

    },
    c: c
};
```

Comment: I'd name this a shorthand method (because when you call this property, its function gets the `this` context as `obj`, yet).

Comment: Is the OP case yes, but in general you can not use semicolons for any property, so I rather not rename it (I will add a comment though). Thank you for the edit btw!

Comment: Note that there is a subtle difference. In your first snippet, `obj.a` is not a constructor. In the second snippet, `new obj.a` works as usual.

Comment: @GOTO0 That is very accurate indeed.

Comment: @GOTO0, why is that?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez see [my question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193117/constructor-behaving-differently-using-es6-shorthand-notation)

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, when you write:

```
var x = { a (b) {} };
```

It will consider it as:

```
var x = { 
    a: function (b) {

     }
   }
```

For example, you can check this and it will clear your doubt:

```
var x = { a (b) { console.info('function called') } };
x.a();
```

This will call the function which is assigned to property `a` of object `x`.