# Constructor behaving differently using ES6 shorthand notation

Tags: javascript, methods, ecmascript-6, shorthand

ES6 introduced a [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to initialize objects with functions and properties.

```js
// ES6 shorthand notation
const obj1 = {
    a(b) {
        console.log("ES6: obj1");
    }
};

// ES5
var obj2 = {
    a: function a(b) {
        console.log("ES5: obj2");
    }
};

obj2.a();
obj1.a();

new obj2.a();
new obj1.a();
```

However, these different notations behave differently, as you can see. If I do `new obj1.a()` in the browser (tested Chrome and Firefox), I get a `TypeError: obj1.a is not a constructor`. `new obj2.a()` behaves completely normally.

What happens here? Does anyone have an explanation, and/or links to documentation/specification?

Comment: *methods* (using method definitions in class or object literals) and arrow functions cannot be used with `new`. You'll have to use on old-fashioned `function` or a `class` constructor for that.

Comment: Pre-ES6, functions and constructors were all mixed up. ES6 attempts to differentiate them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/) isn't very direct about explaining this, but we can follow a short chain..

We'll start at [EvaluateNew](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-evaluatenew), since that's the behaviour we're wondering about. Step 7 is clearly the one we're looking for here:

> 7. If IsConstructor(*constructor*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.

So [IsConstructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-isconstructor) is where we need to look next.

Both the summary and the steps describe this:

> The abstract operation IsConstructor determines if *argument*, which must be an ECMAScript language value, is a function object with a [[Construct]] internal method.
>
> ---
>
> 1. If Type(*argument*) is not Object, return **false**.
> 2. If *argument* has a [[Construct]] internal method, return **true**.
> 3. Return **false**.

So, judging by the looks of it, our `obj1.a` doesn't have a [[Construct]] internal method. Let's look for where it says that it shouldn't have one..

Here's what we're looking for, [PropertyDefinitionEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation). The first step is useful here:

> Let methodDef be DefineMethod of MethodDefinition with argument *object*.

That calls [DefineMethod](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-definemethod) with just one argument, *object*. Let's look at DefineMethod - here's what we need:

> With parameters object and optional parameter functionPrototype.
>
> ---
>
> 6. If *functionPrototype* was passed as a parameter, let *kind* be `Normal`; otherwise let *kind* be `Method`.
> 7. Let *closure* be FunctionCreate(kind, *[more arguments snipped]*).

Since *functionPrototype* was *not* passed as a parameter, the kind is `Method`. Let's look at what [FunctionCreate](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functioncreate) does with that:

> 2. If *kind* is not `Normal`, let *allocKind* be `"non-constructor"`.
> 3. Else, let *allocKind* be `"normal"`.
> 4. Let F be FunctionAllocate(*[other arguments snipped]*, *allocKind*).

*Now* we're getting close! We just need to look at [FunctionAllocate](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functionallocate) does with *allocKind* (which is `"non-constructor"` as per the above steps), which is what gives a function all of its internal methods and such.

> 3. If *functionKind* is `"normal"`, let *needsConstruct* be **true**.
> 4. Else, let *needsConstruct* be **false**.
>
> ---
>
> 6. Let *F* be a newly created ECMAScript function object with the internal slots listed in [Table 27](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#table-27). All of those internal slots are initialized to **undefined**.
>
> ---
>
> 9. If *needsConstruct* is **true**, then
>
>    a. Set *F*'s [[Construct]] internal method to the definition specified in 9.2.2.
>
>    b. Set the [[ConstructorKind]] internal slot of *F* to `"base"`.

Finally! If we go through the relevant steps, we can see since *functionKind* isn't `"normal"`, *needsConstruct* becomes **false**, and so a [[Construct]] internal method is never assigned! Then IsConstructor sees that and returns false, and so EvaluateNew fails.

MDN describes this behaviour very simply:

> All method definitions are not constructors and will throw a TypeError if you try to instantiate them.

..but now you know *how* they aren't constructors, officially.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the original discussion happens here:
https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2012-07/july-26.md

> MM: three reasons for this:
>
> - precedent in builtins
> - using a method as a constructor is generally nonsense
> - to freeze a class, I have to freeze the .prototype of the methods on the prototype!!

and

> AWB: suggestion: concise methods should be the same for both classes and object literals
>
> - strictness
> - enumerability
> - constructability
> - attributes

That's how both class methods and object methods became non-constructable

Answer (score 1):

Methods declared using this syntax are not intended to be constructable

[Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Comment: And where does the specification say so?

Comment: "All method definitions are not constructors and will throw a TypeError if you try to instantiate them."

Comment: MDN is not the specification.

Comment: You are the only one who used the word 'specification' buddy.

Comment: No, the OP used it too.

Comment: @Gothdo here, basically: [If kind is not Normal, let allocKind be "non-constructor".](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functioncreate). If you trace all the chain through the spec from 'object literal' part to 'function create' part, you will see that `kind` is method and not `normal` there.