# ES6 concise methods and non-concise methods in object literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let module = {
     add: function(a, b){
        return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
     },

    sub(a, b){
        return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    }
};
```

What are the fundamental differences with using either the *concise* method syntax, such as `sub` acove, compared with the traditional *non-concise* method syntax used by `add`?

Apart from the obvious differences between syntaxes, are *concise* and *non-concise* methods essentially the same?

Comment: What do you mean by “better”?

Comment: In my opinion ...

Comment: Are there any pros / cons of using concise methods?

Comment: Or With Arrow Function: `add = (a, b) => a + b`

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions

Comment: Isn't the second format available only in classes?

Comment: There are _differences_, like `sub` not having a `caller`, `arguments` and `prototype` property. Are you asking for those? Asking for _pros and cons_ comes down to opinion or at least circumstances.

Comment: @axiac No. This is just the short-hand method notation for object-initializers.

Comment: @Xufox But it's not an arrow function. https://jsfiddle.net/4etkva0z/

Comment: @CertainPerformance Where did I say that anything was an arrow function?

Comment: @Xufox You didn't, but as in the fiddle, the `arguments` seem to work fine?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I said the _property_ wasn’t there. `module.sub.hasOwnProperty("prototype") === false`, `module.sub.hasOwnProperty("arguments") === false`, etc.

Comment: @Xufox I got it, thanks!

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is true at least for `prototype`. Firefox shows `add` as having `arguments` and `caller` properties, but `hasOwnProperty` doesn’t agree with that. Anyway, most importantly, `sub` [wouldn’t be constructible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41193117/4642212), but `add` would be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One notable difference is that *concise* methods can utilize the [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) keyword and the *non-concise* (aka: *traditional*) methods cannot. This becomes pertinent when changing an object(s) prototype to aid *inheritance*.

To demonstrate this, consider the following gist:

---

**Example:**

```js
const frenchPerson = {
  speak() {
    return 'Bonjour';
  }
};

const englishPerson = {
  speak() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
};

const multilinguist = {
  speak() {
    return `${super.speak()}, Hola`
  }
};

console.log(frenchPerson.speak()) // -> "Bonjour"
console.log(englishPerson.speak()) // -> "Hello"

Object.setPrototypeOf(multilinguist, frenchPerson);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(multilinguist) === frenchPerson); // true

console.log(multilinguist.speak()); // -> "Bonjour, Hola"

Object.setPrototypeOf(multilinguist, englishPerson);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(multilinguist) === englishPerson); // true

console.log(multilinguist.speak()); // -> "Hello, Hola"
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. Firstly note all objects; `frenchPerson`, `englishPerson`, and `multilinguist`, utilize the *concise* method syntax.
2. As you can see, the *concise* method named `speak` of the `multilinguist` object utilizes `super.speak()` to point to the it's object prototype (whichever that may be).
3. After setting the prototype of `multilinguist` to `frenchPerson` we invoke `multilinguist`'s `speak()` method - which replies/logs:

   > `Bonjour, Hola`
4. Then we set the prototype of `multilinguist` to `englishPerson` and ask `multilinguist` to `speak()` again - this time it replies/logs:

   > `Hello, Hola`

---

**What happens when `multilinguist`'s `speak()` method is *non-concise*?**

When using a *non-concise* `speak()` method in the `multilinguist` object in addition to the `super` reference it returns:

> `Syntax Error`

As shown in the following example:

```js
const englishPerson = {
  speak() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
};

const multilinguist = {
  speak: function() {           // <--- non-concise method
    return `${super.speak()}, Hola`
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(multilinguist, englishPerson);

console.log(multilinguist.speak()); // -> Syntax Error
```

**Additional Note:**

To achieve the above with a *non-concise* method; [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) can be utilized as a replacement for `super` as demonstrated in the following:

```js
const englishPerson = {
  speak() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
};

// Non-concise method utilizing `call` instead of `super`
const multilinguist = {
  speak: function() {
    return `${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).speak.call(this)}, Hola!`
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(multilinguist, englishPerson);

console.log(multilinguist.speak()); // -> "Hello, Hola!"
```

Comment: Note that the reason methods are compatible with the `super` keyword is because they get assigned an internal `[[HomeObject]]` property (see section [9.2.12](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-makemethod) of the specs). The `[[HomeObject]]` property corresponds to the object on which the method is defined on, which can then be used to get the prototype of that object.

Comment: The chapter [More Powerful Prototypes](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-more-powerful-prototypes) in _Understanding ES6_ by Nicholas Zakas gives a good example showing how the last code snippet is not a perfect substitute for `super`.