# Does Vue Need The Function Keyword in Computed Properties and Methods?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2

I see computed properties and methods in the Vue docs like this:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    foo: function() { return 'foo'; }
  },
  methods: {
    bar: function(x) { return 'bar ' + x; }
  }
}
```

However, I've also seen the `function` keyword omitted. Is this allowed? Are there any drawbacks?

```
export default {
  computed: {
    foo() { return 'foo'; }
  },
  methods: {
    bar(x) { return 'bar ' + x; }
  }
}
```

Comment: The only difference between them is that the shorthand function cannot be used as a constructor function with `new` operator ([Constructor behaving differently using ES6 shorthand notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41193117)). But, this is inside Vue object, so it is irrelevant here. You can use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed, starting from ES6.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

*Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name.*

```js
const obj = {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
};

console.log(obj.foo());
// expected output: "bar"
```

**Drawbacks:**

- This syntax is not supported by IE11
- You probably need a transpiler, like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to use this syntax in non-supported environments